# layout-sw720dp is ignored for 10 inch tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker-GooglePlay)

I have layout for

phone
7 inch tablets (layout-sw600dp-land), so it changes layout only in landscape
10 inch tablets (layout-sw720dp) - DOES NOT WORK

layouts in the layout sw-600dp-land and sw720dp are identical

so my phone works well, my 7 inch tablet works well - showing phone layout in portrait and 7 inch layout in landscrape. However, when I tried to apply the same logic to the 10 inch tablet, it does not pick up sw720dp layout. Please help me understand why?

10 inch tablet is emulator (Nexus 10, i tried APIs 16, 23)
phone and 7 inch tablet were tested on the physical devices and work perfectly.

[image]

Comment: How do you know it does not pick up the layout for 10-inch tablet? You just said "layouts in the layout sw-600dp-land and sw720dp are identical"

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin coz, I know what the layout in 600 looks like and 7 inch loads it. However, my 10 inch loads phone layout (from general layout folder)

Comment: what is the file name of the layout you want to load? how do you know it loads phone layout instead? I see you don't have "-land" in your 720dp folder.. Are you sure you are testing in landscape mode? In portrait it will pick up the default file if there is no landscape resource.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin no, activity_main.xml. layout-sw720dp should load the same layout for both land and portrait orientation. In sw600-land i have layout for the tablet which dual screen layout, and copying it into sw720 should make the same layout load in 10 inch only for the both orientations.

Comment: What is the density and resolution of the 10 inch emulator screen? A physical nexus 10 is 2560x1600 at 300ppi. Is your AVD the same as that or different?

Comment: @NigelK yes my emulator is identical

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the tablet emulators such as the Nexus 10.  It does not render the layouts correctly as you are experiencing. Try creating a new emulator without the skin and your layouts should work properly.